# Scala's mutable.LinkedList append

Tags: scala

Quote from sources:

> If `this` is empty then it does nothing and returns `that`.

There are some questions where authors ask **how** append to LinkedList, but i didn't found, **why** LinkedList is designed with such behavior.

And one more questions, does Scala has any List with add/append (which changes `this` with O(1)) and map operations?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the documentation for append in the [mutable LinkedList API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList) there is something more that least explains the O(n) performance of append:

```
def append(that: LinkedList[A]): LinkedList[A]
```

> If this is empty then it does nothing and returns that. Otherwise,
>   appends that to this. The append requires a full traversal of this.

append takes a second `LinkedList` (`that`) and appends it to the current one (`this`). If the current `LinkedList` is empty the result of appending a second `LinkedList` to an empty one is just the second `LinkedList`.

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I didn't think this could be controversial or require particular design decisions.

As for performance characteristics of operations on scala collection I'm not sure if there's anything newer, but I've always pointed [to this doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html).

Comment: I just want to know, why LinkedList has such behavior. I thought that simple list should have add operation with const time (like java.util.LinkedList). Most likely i don't understand something.


I use ListBuffer now (for map and add), but isn't it ugly?

Comment: java.util.LinkedList is really a doubly-linked list.  It has constant time add because the position of the end is known.